# Serving static subpages in drupal 8 via htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-8

We have drupal 8 site with a folder in docroot. Lets say its in a folder called `micrositefolder`. It contains a single index.html file.

Now let's say `micrositefolder` lives on `fullsite.com`. I dont want someone to access the microsite via `fullsite.com/micrositefolder`, but instead only accessible via `mymicrosite.com`

I have already achieved that with the following:

```
# Prevent access to the static site from non-static site hosts.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/micrositefolder [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mymiscrosite
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,R=301]

# Only serve the static site if host begins with mymiscrosite.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mymiscrosite

# Don't loop anything targeting the actual mask directory, to allow
# for linked scripts, stylesheets etc in the static HTML
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/micrositefolder/

#Any requests that made it this far are served from the /micrositefolder/ directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /micrositefolder/$1 [PT]
```

That works great. I can now visit mymicrosite.com and it serves me that index.html in that folder.

I now have to include another page on that microsite. The url would be `mymicrosite.com/ronnie`. I created a folder inside of `micrositefolder` called `ronnie` with another `index.html` in it.

When I try to go to that url (mymicrosite.com/ronnie) it is being rewritten to `mymicrosite.com/micrositefolder/ronnie/` and I cannot figure out why. I am pretty sure it has to do with that last line in my code snippet, but I cannot figure out how to make it just be `mymicrosite.com/ronnie`

One thing to note is if I view the url via `mymicrosite.com/ronnie/` it works, but if I dont include the slash at the end it redirects to `mymicrosite.com/micrositefolder/ronnie`

Comment: Try your URL with trailing slash to make `mymicrosite.com/ronnie/` after clearing browser cache

Comment: @anubhava yes I tried that and it does work, but thats not the problem. The problem is if I dont include the trailing slash it turns into `mymicrosite.com/micrositefolder/ronnie`

Answer (score 1):

You can add this rule below your existing rules in site root .htacess:

```
# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L]
```

This will add a trailing slash if current request is pointing to a directory.

Problem with your proposed approach (in the answer) is that:

- It will perform a trailing slash `301` redirect even if it is an invalid URI such as `mymicrosite.com/qwerty111`
- For cases like `mymicrosite.com/ronnie` where `/micrositefolder/ronnie` is an actual directory, it will perform an extra `301` redirect before showing `index.html`

Comment: unfortunately, this is still resulting in `mymicrosite.com/micrositefolder/ronnie` when I input `mymicrosite.com/ronnie`

Comment: No that's not the behavior I am getting. Did you delete `micrositefolder/.htaccess` and cleared browser cache?

Comment: I didn't delete, just commented everything out. The problem probably resides in something else going on in the main .htaccess. The default .htaccess with drupal comes with a bunch of other stuff in it. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.0.x/.htaccess

Comment: I think if you remove `micrositefolder/.htaccess` it may work. I am checking Drupal .htaccess as well

Answer (score 0):

Adding an .htaccess inside the `micrositefolder` with the below seems to have solved my issue

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```